# Force.com and Customer Portal Login

Tags: force.com, customer-portal

I am in the process of converting my Customer Portal into a Force.com fo greater customisation of the behavior, look and feel of the site.

Right now I have started off really basic by having three pages.
- Homepage
- News Page (essentually just loads news items onto the page)
- My Orders page (will eventually load the records of my Service_Orders__c object)

The first two pages work fine without any login or redirect to the authentication page which is as expected as I want these pubic. The Orders page as expected does prompt the user to login, this is done by restricing access to the page to only my 'Customer Portal User License' profile. After logging into with my portal profile credentials the 'Orders Page' does load but it is wrapped in the Customer Portal template as if it was loaded through Customer Portal instead of my site. How can I change this behavior? I want only the page content to be displayed, it should not be wrapped around the customer portal.

This is the only code displayed in my Orders page as of now, I have yet to add the functions to list records (which will come later):

```
<apex:page>

<h1>Site Title</h1>

<ul>
    <li><a href="https://dev-site.cs14.force.com/">Home</a></li>
    <li><apex:outputLink value="/apex/force_Orders">My Orders</apex:outputLink></li>
    <li><apex:outputLink value="/apex/force_News">News</apex:outputLink></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>

This is the orders page
```

Comment: You can use the `showHeader` and `sidebar` attributes on the <apex:page> element, but I'm not sure if that will help you.

Comment: @Lex Please convert into answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the default sidebar and header to be shown, use the `showHeader` and `sidebar` attributes on the `<apex:page>` element:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
```

Some more documentation on the page element: [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_compref_component.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fpages_compref_component.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)